# Left side menu sliding in correctly but the body not sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am making a left side menu that slides in when u click it, and it is working fine the animation is correct, when I try to animate the div with class .bd (I'm using this as the body of the page) it doesn't animate. It moves correctly but it is abrupt and have no idea why it is doing that, I included a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgYQVJ) and I will also include a code snippet it is giving me the same result in both of them.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.opener').click(function(){
  function name(){
   if($('.bd').css('margin-left') == ($('body').width()*25)/100+'px'){
    $('.bd').css({
     'animation-name':'expandbody',
     'anmation-duration':'2s',
     'margin-left':'0',
     'width':'100%'
    });
    $('.menu').css({
     'animation-name':'closemenu',
     'animation-duration':'1s',
     'width':'0%',
     'display':'none'
    });
   }else{
    $('.bd').css({
     'animation-name':'smallerbody',
     'anmation-duration':'2s',
     'margin-left':'25%',
     'width':'75%'
    });
    $('.menu').css({
     'animation-name':'expandmenu',
     'animation-duration':'1s',
     'width':'25%',
     'display':'block'
    });
   }
  }
  name();
 });
});
```

```css
html,body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
.menu{
 width:25%;
 height:100%;
 position:fixed;
 background-color:#0A0A0A;
 display:none;
}
.menu ul{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
.menu ul li{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
 border-bottom:1px solid #F0F0F0;
 height:50px;
 line-height:50px;
}
.menu ul li a{
 display:block;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
 color:#F0F0F0;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:1.5em;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 transition:all .5s;
}
.fa{
 width:25px;
 margin-left:10px;
 margin-right:25px;
}
.caret{
 float:right;
 display:block;
 width:0px;
 height:0px;
 border-top:10px solid transparent;
 border-right:10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom:10px solid transparent;
 border-left:10px solid #F0F0F0;
 position:relative;
 top:13px;
 display:none;
}
.menu ul li:hover{
 background-color:#1A1A1A;
}
.menu ul li:hover a>.caret{
 display:block;
}
.bar{
 position:fixed;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background:#0A0A0A;
 color:#A0A0A0;
}
.opener{
 line-height:40px;
 font-size:2em;
 margin-left:25px;
 padding-left:6px;
 padding-right:6px;
 margin-top:5px;
 margin-bottom:5px;
 max-width:30px;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-weight:bold;
 transition:all .5s;
}
.opener:hover{
 color:#F0F0F0;
}
.bd{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:#F0F0F0;
}

/* Animations*/

@keyframes expandmenu{
 from{
  width:0%;
  display:none;
 }
 to{
  width:25%;
  display:block;
 }
}
@keyframes closemenu{
 from{
  width:25%;
  display:block;
 }
 to{
  width:0%;
  display:none;
 }
}
@keyframes expandbody{
 from{
  width:75%;
  margin-left:25%;
 }
 to{
  width:100%;
  margin-left:0%;
 }
}
@keyframes smallerbody{
 from{
  width:100%;
  margin-left:0%;
 }
 to{
  width:75%;
  margin-left:25%;

 }
}
```

```html
<head>
 <title>Queltick | Admin Dashboard</title>
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu">
<ul>
 <li><a class="menuitem" href="#"><span class="fa fa-home"></span>Home <span class="caret"></span></a></li>
 <li><a class="menuitem" href="#"><span class="fa fa-user"></span>Users <span class="caret"></span></a></li>
 <li><a class="menuitem" href="#"><span class="fa fa-book"></span>Posts <span class="caret"></span></a></li>
 <li><a class="menuitem" href="#"><span class="fa fa-users"></span>Groups <span class="caret"></span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="bd">
 <div class="bar">

  <div class="opener">
  &#9776;
  </div>

  <div class="logo"></div>

 </div>

</div>
</body>
```

EDIT:
I changed `($(window).width()*25)/100+'px'` to `($('body').width()*25)/100+'px'` to make it more responsive

Comment: it works fine on my dude. I added some bunch of h1 tags to populate in your .bd content right before the last div and it pushes them totally fine, what seems to be the exact problem.

Comment: the body is pushed correctly for me to but the push is not animated for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it was two minor spelling mistakes on lines 7 and 20 'anmation-duration' should be 'animation-duration'

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.opener').click(function() {
    function name() {
      if ($('.bd').css('margin-left') >= ($('body').width() * 25) / 100 + 'px') {
        $('.bd').css({
          'animation-name': 'expandbody',
          'animation-duration': '2s',
          'margin-left': '0',
          'width': '100%'
        });
        $('.menu').css({
          'animation-name': 'closemenu',
          'animation-duration': '1s',
          'width': '0%',
          'display': 'none'
        });
      } else {
        $('.bd').css({
          'animation-name': 'smallerbody',
          'animation-duration': '2s',
          'margin-left': '25%',
          'width': '75%'
        });
        $('.menu').css({
          'animation-name': 'expandmenu',
          'animation-duration': '1s',
          'width': '25%',
          'display': 'block'
        });
      }
    }
    name();
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.menu {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #0A0A0A;
  display: none;
}
.menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #F0F0F0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.fa {
  width: 25px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
.caret {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #F0F0F0;
  position: relative;
  top: 13px;
  display: none;
}
.menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #1A1A1A;
}
.menu ul li:hover a>.caret {
  display: block;
}
.bar {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #0A0A0A;
  color: #A0A0A0;
}
.opener {
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  max-width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.opener:hover {
  color: #F0F0F0;
}
.bd {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
/* Animations*/

@keyframes expandmenu {
  from {
    width: 0%;
    display: none;
  }
  to {
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
  }
}
@keyframes closemenu {
  from {
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
  }
  to {
    width: 0%;
    display: none;
  }
}
@keyframes expandbody {
  from {
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}
@keyframes smallerbody {
  from {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Queltick | Admin Dashboard</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="menuitem" href="#"><span class="fa fa-home"></span>Home <span class="caret"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menuitem" href="#"><span class="fa fa-user"></span>Users <span class="caret"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menuitem" href="#"><span class="fa fa-book"></span>Posts <span class="caret"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menuitem" href="#"><span class="fa fa-users"></span>Groups <span class="caret"></span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="bd">
    <div class="bar">

      <div class="opener">
        &#9776;
      </div>

      <div class="logo"></div>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: oh my god... jesus

Comment: no sweat, it happens. many hours of my time have tracked back to the odd missing dot or comma.

Comment: hahahahah well thank you for the fix i accepted your answer, i do have another issue though i was wondering if u can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the animation-name and animation-duration to animation and put them both together. i think animation-name is not correct way to put it. And it worked

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.opener').click(function(){
        function name(){
            if($('.bd').css('margin-left') == ($('body').width()*25)/100+'px'){
                $('.bd').css({
                    'animation':'expandbody 2s',
                    'margin-left':'0',
                    'width':'100%'
                });
                $('.menu').css({
                    'animation':'closemenu 1s',
                    'width':'0%',
                    'display':'none'
                });
            }else{
                $('.bd').css({
                    'animation':'smallerbody 2s',
                    'margin-left':'25%',
                    'width':'75%'
                });
                $('.menu').css({
                    'animation':'expandmenu 1s',
                    'width':'25%',
                    'display':'block'
                });
            }
        }
        name();
    });
});
```

Comment: can u please explain ? what is wrong with specifying animation name and animation duration seperatly

Comment: cash me ousside, lol this didnt work as i need it to i think i know what the issue is

Comment: i think bottom answer is right tho but it works on mine. i learned animation keyframes as one line animation: <animationname> <duration> <occurance>;

Comment: btw your .bd is pushing in 2 s while menu is pushing in 1s, looks weird change that both to 1 or 2 s

Answer (score 0):

for anyone interested i fixed it
here is the fix:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.opener').click(function(){
  function name(){
   if($('.bd').css('margin-left') == ($(window).width()*25)/100+'px'){
    $('.bd').css({
     'animation-name':'expandbody',
     'animation-duration':'1s',
     'margin-left':'0',
     'width':'100%'
    });
    $('.menu').css({
     'animation':'closemenu 1s',
     'margin-left':'-25%'
    });
   }else{
    $('.bd').css({
     'animation-name':'smallerbody',
     'animation-duration':'1s',
     'margin-left':'25%',
     'width':'75%'
    });
    $('.menu').css({
     'animation-name':'expandmenu',
     'animation-duration':'1s',
     'margin-left':'0%',
     'display':'block'
    });
   }
  }
  name();
 });
});
```

```css
html,body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
.menu{
 width:25%;
 height:100%;
 position:fixed;
 background-color:#0A0A0A;
 margin-left:-25%;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset -2px 2px 10px -3px rgba(240,240,240,1);
-moz-box-shadow: inset -2px 2px 10px -3px rgba(240,240,240,1);
box-shadow: inset -2px 2px 10px -3px rgba(240,240,240,1);
}
.menu-title{
 height:50px;
 line-height:50px;
 font-size:1.7em;
 font-family:Arial;
 color:#F0F0F0;
 width:calc(100% - 5px);
 padding-left:5px;
 border-bottom:2px solid #F0F0F0;
}
.menu ul{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
.menu ul li{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
 border-bottom:1px solid #F0F0F0;
 height:50px;
 line-height:50px;
}
.menu ul li a{
 display:block;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
 color:#F0F0F0;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:1.5em;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 transition:all .5s;
}
.fa{
 width:25px;
 margin-left:25px;
 margin-right:25px;
}
.caret{
 float:right;
 display:block;
 width:0px;
 height:0px;
 border-top:10px solid transparent;
 border-right:10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom:10px solid transparent;
 border-left:10px solid #F0F0F0;
 position:relative;
 top:13px;
 display:none;
}
.menu ul li:hover{
 background-color:#1A1A1A;
}
.menu ul li:hover a>.caret{
 display:block;
}
.bar{
 position:fixed;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background:#0A0A0A;
 color:#A0A0A0;
}
.opener{
 line-height:40px;
 font-size:2em;
 margin-left:25px;
 padding-left:6px;
 padding-right:6px;
 margin-top:5px;
 margin-bottom:5px;
 max-width:30px;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-weight:bold;
 transition:all .5s;
}
.opener:hover{
 color:#F0F0F0;
}
.bd{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:#1A1A1A;
}

/* Animations*/

@keyframes expandmenu{
 from{
  margin-left:-25%;
 }
 to{
  margin-left:0%;
 }
}
@keyframes closemenu{
 from{
  margin-left:0%;
 }
 to{
  margin-left:-25%;
 }
}
@keyframes expandbody{
 from{
  width:75%;
  margin-left:25%;
 }
 to{
  width:100%;
  margin-left:0%;
 }
}
@keyframes smallerbody{
 from{
  width:100%;
  margin-left:0%;
 }
 to{
  width:75%;
  margin-left:25%;

 }
}
```

```html
<head>
 <title>Queltick | Admin Dashboard</title>
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu">
<div class="menu-title">
&#9776; Menu
</div>
<ul>
 <li><a class="menuitem" href="#"><span class="fa fa-home"></span>Home <span class="caret"></span></a></li>
 <li><a class="menuitem" href="#"><span class="fa fa-user"></span>Users <span class="caret"></span></a></li>
 <li><a class="menuitem" href="#"><span class="fa fa-book"></span>Posts <span class="caret"></span></a></li>
 <li><a class="menuitem" href="#"><span class="fa fa-users"></span>Groups <span class="caret"></span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="bd">
 <div class="bar">

  <div class="opener">
  &#9776;
  </div>

  <div class="logo"></div>

 </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```